# Use symfony objects for sending Swift_message

Tags: php, symfony, email, message

I am trying to create an email that messages all users that are tied to a specific company. If I take the recipients array and add it to my email and test with a single email, I can see all of the user emails print out in the test email. When I try and pass that same recipients array into setTo instead of using a single to email address I get a message **"Warning: Illegal offset type"**

```
    $company = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:Customer')->findOneBy(array('accountId' => $compare->getCustomerAccount()));

    $recipients = [];
    foreach($company->getUsers() as $user){
        array_push($recipients, $user);
    }
    array_push($recipients, $company->getCsr());

    $newComment = new Comment();
    $newComment->setDetails($comment);
    $newComment->setUser($this->getUser());

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->flush();

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($fromEmail)
        ->setTo($recipients)
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'Bundle:Comment:email_users.html.twig', array(
                    'subject' => $subject,
                    'comment' => $comment,
                    'company' => $company,
                    'proof' => $proof
                )
            )
        )
        ->setContentType('text/html')
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: Looks like you're pushing User-objects instead of email addresses?

Comment: @ccKep yup, How do I access emails of the symfony user object? getEmail is not a function.

Comment: Well, you've got to have the email stored somewhere if you intend to send mails to them? What does your user entity look like?

Comment: Our user object extends the base symfony user "BaseUser" and we have no getUser function. I could try adding one but I feel like there should be one built in yet it appears there is not

Comment: You probably mean BaseUser from the FOSUserBundle?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: If you really do extend that you should have a `getEmail` method in it (see [Line 218 in User.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L218)). Just try using `array_push($recipients, $user->getEmail());` and removing `array_push($recipients, $company->getCsr());` for now (I have no idea if getCsr returns another User object or whatever it returns otherwise).

Comment: I was able to add a new function in my user class that references the getEmail function in the parent. Check my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to my user class which extends BaseUser:

```
/**
 * Sets the email.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return parent::getEmail();
}
```

Then I was able to run getEmail on each user

```
$recipients = [];
foreach($company->getUsers() as $user){
    array_push($recipients, $user->getEmail());
}
array_push($recipients, $company->getCsr()->getEmail());
```

Email was sent successfully!

Comment: First part is obsolete, if you don't define that function (and your base class does, and it's public - which it is in FOSUserBundle) it'll just get called anyway. Glad you got it working though!

Comment: That's what I assumed but I tried getEmail() originally and it said it wasn't a function

Answer (score 1):

Se setTo accept an associative array with email and name (check [here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#quick-reference-for-creating-a-message) in the doc), so you should modify your code with something like:

```
foreach($company->getUsers() as $user){
    array_push($recipients, [$user->getEmail() => $user->getName()]);
}
array_push($recipients, $company->getCsr()->getEmail());
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs, because you're trying to set the recipients with an array of `$user` objects instead of an associative array of strings. When trying to access the index of an array with an object or an array as the index, you will see that error message.

Your `$recipients`array should look more like `array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name')` and you should be fine.

Your code could look like this:

```
    $recipients = [];
    foreach($company->getUsers() as $user){
        array_push($recipients, $user->getEmail());
    }
    array_push($recipients, $company->getCsr()->getEmail());
```

I'm just assuming that your user object has a getter method `getEmail()` which returns the user email address as a string.